Gates conditional on multiple measurement outcomes
We can apply gates conditional on measurement outcomes using:
circ.append("CNOT",[stim.target_rec(-k),target])

Say I want the gate to be applied conditional on the function of a few measurement outcomes (E.g. apply X if stim.target_rec(-k) + stim.target_rec(-k-1) + stim.target_rec(-k-2) == 1.). Is this possible using append?
I see how it can be done using TableauSimulator().

No, stim doesn't allow this via append.
For example, consider this hypothetical circuit that you can't actually say that does doubly controlled feedback:
    TICK

    M 0 1
    CX (rec[-1]&rec[-2]) 0

    TICK

    M 0
    OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE rec[-1]

What should stim.Circuit.detecting_regions() return for this circuit? At the second tick, the observable is just about to finish its life by entering a measurement of qubit 0. So at this point it is equal to Z0. But what should it be at the first tick? Every possible Pauli product you can write down fails to work; none of them deterministically evolve into Z0 at the second tick. The only thing that would work is Z0 * (CZ 0 1). The observable has escaped the Pauli product subspace. So all analysis based on assuming Pauli products is going to start failing. You won't be able to compute detector error models, you won't be able to compute detecting regions, you won't be able to compute stabilizer flows, etc, etc, etc.
It is still possible to sample efficiently (e.g. skip the feedback when collecting the reference sample, and then propagate the feedback the same as errors during flip simulation). But all the analysis around the sampling breaks (or rather: gets a lot harder). So that's why it's not allowed.
